# How does this translate to SQL to LINQ?

Tags: c#, sql, linq, sql-server-2008, linq-to-sql

Just wondering what the best (fastest execution time) method for translating the following SQL to LINQ to SQL is?

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 * FROM HealthIndicators WHERE LogDate = getdate())
     UPDATE HealthIndicators SET Timeouts = 32
ELSE INSERT INTO HealthIndicators (Timeouts, 32)
```

I apologise if this is a repost but I haven't been able to find an answer on the subject (I'm new, please be nice!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var d = DateTime.Today; // or .Now
if (db.HealthIndicators.FirstOrDefault(h => h.LogDate == d) != null)
// or Any(h => h.LogDate == d)
{
    // update
}
else
{
    // insert
}
```

Comment: Wow, so quick. This is above my knowledge of linq to sql but definitely prompting me to study more, thank-you

Comment: @Michael: Glad to help :) btw I hope you use Entity Framework rather then LINQ to SQL as far the first is more feature-rich (and is more real ORM) then the second

Comment: I've gone to implement this but Visual Studio is coming up with a syntax error for .Any() - what library do I need to include to utilize this?

Answer (score 1):

I would just add one more item to the answer above.  The answer above uses a DateTime.Today which uses the time from the machine the code is running on instead of getdate() which grabs the time from Sql Server.  This can matter if your application has a separate database server.  To do this you have to add the following function to your ORM.

```
[Function(Name="GetDate", IsComposable=true)] 
 public DateTime GetSystemDate() 
 {   
    MethodInfo mi = MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod() as MethodInfo;   
    return (DateTime)this.ExecuteMethodCall(this, mi, new object[]{}).ReturnValue; 
 }
```